# How to activate madExcept on a REST Backend?

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria, madexcept

How can madExcept be activated to log Exceptions and MemoryLeaks on a RAD Server REST Backend module ?.

I try adding its units to the project, like a desktop application does, and although it compiles and runs, madExcept is not catching the exceptions and memory leaks, and not reporting them on a log file.

```
uses
  ...
  ...
  madExcept,
  madLinkDisAsm,
  madListHardware,
  madListProcesses,
  madListModules
```

Is there another way to configure madExcept so it will log the issues that occur on that Backend ?.

I only need it to run with the debug builds that run on Delphi's EMSDevServer.exe, I don't intend to activate it on production (hosted by Apache on Linux) because of its impact in the performance and memory consumption.

PS: When I added the units to the project, the IDE moved those units to the `requires` section when I saved the DPK file.

```
requires
  rtl,
  emsserverapi,
  dbrtl,
  FireDAC,
  ...
  ...  
  madBasic_,
  madDisAsm_,
  madExcept_;
```

Comment: Ask at http://forum.madshi.net/viewforum.php?f=4 ?

Comment: @mjn thanks, I will post the question there